# External Merged Dictionaries Broken in Silverlight 3 RTM?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, mergeddictionaries

I just want to reference a resource dictionary in a referenced assembly.

Assembly name: ResourceTest.Content

Resource Dictionary Path: ./Dictionary2.xaml

This was working on SL3 Beta 1:

`<ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceTest.Content;component/Dictionary2.xaml" />`

I tried this in Blend 3+Sketchflow and this works (at design time):

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourceTest.Content;component/Dictionary2.xaml" />`

But, either way, when I run from Visual Studio, I get the following error:

Attribute ResourceTest.Content;component/Dictionary2.xaml value is out of range. [Line: 10 Position: 44]

Attribute pack://application:,,,/ResourceTest.Content;component/Dictionary2.xaml value is out of range. [Line: 11 Position: 44]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a / before your Assembly name:

This should work ...

Comment: You are correct. I also found that this can be fixed by opening in Blend 3 and linking to resource dictionaries in other projects. ^_^